# Hiding a windowed application launched by a java application?

Tags: java, powershell, window, hidden, launching-application

I am working on a Java application which has to launch a different application. If I launch the second application using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, it becomes the active process and its window comes before my application's window. What I really want to do is launch the process in "hidden" mode so that its taskbar entry does not appear and its window is initially invisible or behind my application window. Then my application would make it visible or move it to the front when it is good and ready. Is this possible or am I asking for too much?

This is for a demo. So I am not worried about security issues.

**Edit**: Daniel's answer has given me an idea. What if I use Powershell to invoke the application instead of CMD.EXE? Will that let me start the app without the window and then bring the window back? I will be using to launch java to launch PowerShell to launch app, but what the heck!

Comment: Why not launch this external application when your application is "good and ready"? Is there really a need to launch the external application beforehand? Does it take a long time to load?

Comment: Well, the external application takes a hell of a time to load. It basically has to connect to a server over the www to get some info, negotiate a handshake, etc. I cannot let my application wait for all that. So I want to launch it as soon as possible and continue with other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what this other application is, but I'm assuming that it's one that you have no control over (i.e. you can't give it a parameter option to start up in a minimized mode or similar.) Rather than hide the application you're launching, can you just use the toFront() method on your window after the other application has launched to bring your window in front of the other? And then minimize your window when you want to reveal the other one?

I'm the first to admit it's a bit of a bodged solution, but it might work depending on what you're after.

Comment: I like the idea. And I suspect there won't be a clean solution to this. But, here the second window will come to the front for sometime. Also, as Daniel says, I don't know how long it will take to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide these parameters, BUT you can use the "start" command (try it in cmd), which supports these parameters. Eventually you have to call it with a cmd.exe shell, but this will work!

Comment: I am fine with invoking the cmd shell but, if I do use "start", I won't be able to activate the window later. Will I?

Comment: How would you do this if you use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()? This can only be done by sending Window Messages, which is sadly platform dependant. But JNative is a good tool do use for this. You have to use the Windows API to find the window and bring it to front.

Comment: "How would you do this if you use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?": I can't. That's the second part of my problem.